# ¿Como obtener miles de registros de la base de datos en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola a todos de ante mano, muchas gracias por sus aportaciones, me encuentro realizando lo siguiente:

Tengo que obtener miles de registros y mostrarlos en una tabla, para ello uso el método paginate de laravel, esto funciona correctamente cuando el usuario busca registros por 5,10,15,etc, el problema es que hay una opción que muestra todos los registros para ser exactos 7,000 registros y es donde mi aplicación truena.

Tengo el siguiente código en mi método index:

```
   public function index(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $rowsPerPage = (int)$request->input('rowsPerPage');
            $search = $request->input('search');
            $type_register = $request->input('typeRegister');

            $total_incidents = EmployeeIncident::count();
            $rowsPerPage == 0 ? $rowsPerPage = $total_incidents : $rowsPerPage;

            $incidents = EmployeeIncident::with('employee')->search($search)->user()
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate($rowsPerPage);

            return response()->json([
                'incidents' => $incidents,
            ]);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Error'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Solo la query:

```
    $incidents = EmployeeIncident::with('employee')->search($search)->user()
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate($rowsPerPage);
```

He estado investigando y creo que chuck puede ayudarme para esto, pero no sé cómo aplicarlo a mi query eloquent, muchas gracias por sus repuestas y comentarios.

Comment: Incluso si optimizas la consulta (que no son muchos datos para la BD, en realidad), lo que se va a demorar es el navegador pintando todo eso. ¿Realmente _tienes_ que pintar 7000 registros? Eso no es usable :(

Comment: No creo que sea usable la verdad, para eso está el buscador, pero ya vez algunos requerimientos de los clientes tengo que lograrlo si o si:(

Comment: _El cliente no sabe lo que quiere_... pero bueno, para cuando llegue alguien que sí sepa de laravel, ¿qué error ves cuando dices que truena con los 7000 registrotes? En qué capa lo ves? En PHP, en el navegador o dónde? Ve a [edit] y añade esa info.

Comment: solo revisa la documentacion, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#chunking-results

Answer (score 0):

La mejor solución sería hacer una consulta bajo demanda, donde cargarías conforme el usuario haga a rol hacia abajo, no enlistaría los 7000 resultados, pero los iría cargando con respecto se necesiten.
De otra manera no veo razón para que todos los resultados se muestren, a menos que tengas que dar resultados en base a cálculos, pero esos cálculos los puedes hacer perfectamente con un query.
Si una aplicación muestra tantos registros, realmente no está solucionando el problema del cliente.

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [answer] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu respuesta sea marcada como correcta. También proporciona el código de lo que has hecho (en texto, no imagen) para que comiences  a ganar reputación y medallas.

Comment: La idea es buena, pero una respuesta debe incluir la solución que muestra como se aplica esa idea, cosa que falta aquí. Siempre puedes hacer comentarios, una vez que alcances la reputación mínima.